# Wave css effect with: after and: before

Tags: css, reactjs

Hello I'm trying to make a wave effect in the css using before and after

but I'm not able to put my waves on the ends of the top and bot

and I also wanted to rotate the bot's wave so that the waves are pointing down:

code:

```
<div className="App">
  <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
  <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
</div>
```

css:

```
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  background: red;
  height: 50vh;
  position: relative;
}

.App::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  height: 10px;
  background-size: 20px 20px;
  background-image: radial-gradient(
    circle at 10px -5px,
    transparent 12px,
    aquamarine 13px
  );
}
.App::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  height: 10px;
  background-size: 20px 20px;
  background-image: radial-gradient(
    circle at 10px -5px,
    transparent 12px,
    aquamarine 13px
  );
}
```

problem:

[image]

I need to turn the wave effect down:

[image]

and I need to position this wave on top of my div

[image]
example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-morning-fefe4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you mean like this?

```css
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  background: red;
  height: 50vh;
  position: relative;
}

.App::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  height: 10px;
  background-size: 20px 20px;
  background-image: radial-gradient(
    circle at 10px 15px, 
    transparent 12px,
    aquamarine 13px
  );

}
.App::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  height: 10px;
  background-size: 20px 20px;
  background-image: radial-gradient(
    circle at 10px -5px,
    transparent 12px,
    aquamarine 13px
  );
}
```

```css
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  background: red;
  height: 50vh;
  position: relative;
}

.App::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  height: 10px;
  background-size: 20px 20px;
  background-image: radial-gradient(
    circle at 10px -5px,
    transparent 12px,
    aquamarine 13px
  );
}
.App::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  height: 10px;
  background-size: 20px 20px;
  background-image: radial-gradient(
    circle at 10px 15px,
    transparent 12px,
    aquamarine 13px
  );
}
```

Comment: i need it but inverted kk
the top one has to be in the bot

and the bot one has to be at the top

Comment: sorry  not sure what kind you wanted  , so i edited it  to two version CSS .  try both  :)

Comment: thanks bro, but the two are the same

Comment: sorry  i  edited it again .  try it